# SVG Path Data with multiple dots in one value

Tags: parsing, svg

I had to write my own SVG path parser and discovered that I cannot parse some files like [Skull_and_crossbones.svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Skull_and_crossbones.svg) from Wikipedia.
In the second path's data I found `-24.57.56` which is just invalid value and I cannot see how to parse it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [spec for the grammar of path data](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF), you will find the following explanation below:

> The processing of the BNF must consume as much of a given BNF production as possible, stopping at the point when a character is encountered which no longer satisfies the production... for the string `M 0.6.5`, the first coordinate of the "moveto" consumes the characters `0.6` and stops upon encountering the second decimal point because the production of a "coordinate" only allows one decimal point. The result is that the first coordinate will be `0.6` and the second coordinate will be `.5`.

For your example, the production `-24.57.56` is equivalent to `-24.57, 0.56`.

You could also say: Leading zeros before a point, commas and whitespace are **always optional**. Authors writing path data must only use them to avoid ambiguity and make sure that the length of what you can parse as one number fits their intention.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an invalid value. It is two valid values.  The first value is `-24.57` and the second value is `.56`.

The [path data grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#paths-PathDataBNF) does not require there to be spaces between coordinate values.  Sometimes they are required, though, if the result would be wrong.  For example, `1 0.5` cannot be shortened to `10.5`